# Bootstrap4 aligned column

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

My goal is to have a page with some rows. Each row has a label column, a control column and an optional unit of measure column. I would like to have label column be same for each row fitting the larger label.
I'm using Bootstrap 4 to ease my few html knowledge. I did some experiments already, maybe I'm on a wrong path using row & col classes.

- I can have aligned columns doing this, but then when I resize browser window, all columns get smaller even if there is a lot of white space on right

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        Label
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        min
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        Longer Label
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- I can have fixed columns doing this. Now columns are not resized but all labels columns have its own width and are not aligned.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      Label
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      min
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      Longer Label
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this point my idea would be use jquery to set all first columns to same size, but I'm not sure this is good/best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery for layout like this would be incorrect usage. Always use CSS for layouts unless there is a very unique use case.

This is a perfect use case for CSS flexbox. Bootstrap is great but learning CSS flexbox will give you a lot more control of layouts.

Make a flex row and then use a flex:1 and max width on the label.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-morning-d3nhz

Comment: Have A LOT to learn, your advise is a good starting point. Can I somehow "auto" size the labels column like with 'col-auto'

Comment: Yes, I have adjusted the code. The label uses auto. You can add min width to it too if you want to force a width to the largest label. I commented it out.